# Address Sanitizer on a python extension result in AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

Tags: address-sanitizer, ld-preload

c source code as below:

```html
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "demo_c.h"

void func(data_pair* pair) {
  printf("func called");
  pair->len=4;
  pair->data = (char*)malloc(pair->len + 1);
  memset(pair->data, 0, pair->len + 1);
  memcpy(pair->data, "test", 4);
  return;
}
```

```sh
gcc -fpic -c demo_c.c -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address
gcc --share demo_c.o -o libdemo_c.so
```

then I import this library in python like this:

```html
from ctypes import *
demo_c = CDLL('/xxx/libdemo_c.so', RTLD_GLOBAL)
libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')

libc.free.argtypes = [c_void_p]

class entry(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('len',c_int),
                ('data', c_void_p)]

v = entry()
demo_c.func.argtypes = [c_void_p]
demo_c.func(byref(v))
libc.free(v.data)
```

then I run:

```sh
LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libasan.so.5 python demo.py
```

output is:

```html
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==432489==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: BUS on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x7f281c9c90fe bp 0x200000000000003 sp 0x7ffe0c369b20 T0)
    #0 0x7f281c9c90fd in _int_free (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x810fd)
    #1 0x7f281356cdcb in ffi_call_unix64 (/lib64/libffi.so.6+0x5dcb)
    #2 0x7f281356c6f4 in ffi_call (/lib64/libffi.so.6+0x56f4)
    #3 0x7f281377fc6a in _ctypes_callproc (/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so+0x10c6a)
    #4 0x7f2813779a64  (/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so+0xaa64)
    #5 0x7f281d687072 in PyObject_Call (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0x4c072)
    #6 0x7f281d71b845 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0xe0845)
    #7 0x7f281d72264c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0xe764c)
    #8 0x7f281d722751 in PyEval_EvalCode (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0xe7751)
    #9 0x7f281d73bb8e  (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0x100b8e)
    #10 0x7f281d73cd5d in PyRun_FileExFlags (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0x101d5d)
    #11 0x7f281d73dfe8 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0x102fe8)
    #12 0x7f281d74f19e in Py_Main (/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0+0x11419e)
    #13 0x7f281c96a554 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x22554)
    #14 0x40068d  (/usr/bin/python2.7+0x40068d)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: BUS (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x810fd) in _int_free
==432489==ABORTING
```

But if I wrap libc.so's free in demo_c.c and call it instead of directly calling free directly in python code, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you allocate your memory with Asan's `malloc` and later try to release it with libc's `free`. This is not going to work as different allocators are generally incompatible.

Comment: If I do not recomplie the c code, Is there any asan_options can solve this?

Comment: Actually I just want this python can run correctly, since this demo python script in my project is not used to detach the shared library's memory leak. Another task will do.

Comment: @zzyy Make another function in your library to free memory via `free` and call that instead of `libc.free`.